# Simple Excel VBA Run-time error 91 : “Object variable or with block variable not set ”

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I'm trying to create a simple bit of code to make sizing userforms easier.

Each time the code runs it fires a Runtime error 91 when I close the userform.

The code is as follows:

Within the UForm initialize

```
Private Sub UserForm_initialize()

Dim objFormName As Object
    Set objFormName = Me
    fnFormStartup objFormName

Call UIDimensions(300, 300, Me)

Me.Show

End Sub
```

UIDimensions code

```
Sub UIDimensions(h As Integer, w As Integer, objUserform As Object)

objUserform.Height = h
objUserform.Width = w

End Sub
```

Any help appreciated as to why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: At first glance I would remove `Me.Show` from the `initialize`event.

Comment: Do you have any code in the Terminate event?